# Kotlin app keeps crashing on run time when trying to load a screen which get details from firebase

Tags: android, kotlin

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment, PID: 5642
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.activities.ShoppingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your manifest's <application />'s android:name attribute?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your manifest's <application />'s android:name attribute?
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.createComponent(ActivityComponentManager.java:76)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.generatedComponent(ActivityComponentManager.java:66)
        at lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.activities.Hilt_ShoppingActivity.generatedComponent(Hilt_ShoppingActivity.java:45)
        at lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.activities.Hilt_ShoppingActivity.inject(Hilt_ShoppingActivity.java:67)
        at lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.activities.Hilt_ShoppingActivity$1.onContextAvailable(Hilt_ShoppingActivity.java:38)
        at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:362)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:217)
        at lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.activities.ShoppingActivity.onCreate(ShoppingActivity.kt:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I get this error when I try to load a given screen of the application. How can I resolve this?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MobileApplicationDevelopment"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ShoppingActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginRegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ShoppingActivity.kt

```
package lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.activities

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View.inflate
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.R
import lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.databinding.ActivityShoppingBinding

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ShoppingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val binding by lazy {
        ActivityShoppingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstancesState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstancesState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.shoppingHostFragment)
        binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

}
```

Comment: The error message says "Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your manifest's 's android:name attribute?" - so where is your `android:name` on the `application` tag in your manifest?

Answer (score 2):

you should create application class that extend Application() like this :

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : Application(){...}
```

then in your manifest add this line :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        ...>

         <activity
           android:name=".ShoppingActivity"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

for more information check link below :

[Hilt Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)